# Scrapy: How to traverse AJAX based navigation?

Tags: scrapy

I am traversing [this URL](http://www.leparking.fr/voiture-occasion/Porsche--targa-g.html#!/voiture-occasion/Porsche--targa-g.html%3Fslider_millesime%3D1940%7C1985). In this `javascript:ctrl.set_pageReload(1)` function making an AJAX call which then loads page data. How can I write my `Rule(LinkExtractor().` to make a traverse or is there some other way?

Answer (score 0):

What is AJAX? Its just simply a request to a link with GET or POST method.

You can check it in Inspect-Element view.

[image]

Click on the button you are talking about, then see where is the AJAX going to?

Also instead of scraping URLs via `Rule(LinkExtractor()`, remove `start_urls` and `def parse()` method and do this,

```
def start_requests(self):

       yield Request(url= URLE_HERE, callback=self.parse_detail_page)
```